# Flavorful beef broth without bones?

Tags: beef, broth

is it possible to make flavorful beef broth as a base for Pho/Soup etc without bones?

I'm not minding the body/gelatinous or not, just the flavor.

on our market here the butchers sell meat scrap gained from bones i'm planning to use that for economic reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the most flavor, you will need to roast/brown the meat scraps.

Let them get a nice brown color.

you could add aromatic vegetables (onion, carrots, celery) as well to the roasting pan.

Comment: I will testify that roast scraps make fine broth.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and tips. highly appreciated